# How do I get $_POST value in php controller from php jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

this is my first time posting here but I can't seem to find an answer to the question I have. I have been using stack for years now but this is one of the first times where I just can't seem to find an answer. If I should be doing something differently please feel free to let me know.

I am dynamically populating buttons based on file names present in a directory. I need to send the name of the button clicked to my controller using jquery and ajax. I am using the following code to do this:

```
$currentDir = getcwd();
                $files = scandir($currentDir);
                $count = 0;
                foreach ($files as $name) {
                    if(preg_match("/^sma\w*/", $name)){
                        $workingFiles = substr($name, strpos($name, "_") + 1);
                        $availableActions = explode(".", $workingFiles);
                        $class_action = $availableActions[0];
                        $buttonName = $class_action;
                        $count ++;
                        ?>
                        <button id="<?php echo $class_action;?>" class="actionButtons"><? echo $buttonName; ?></button>
                            <script>
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                    $("#<?php echo $class_action;?>").click(function(){

                                        var class_action = <?php echo $class_action;?>    
                                        $.ajax({ url: url + '?action=GetStatus&action=Execute',
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            data: JSON.stringify({action: "GetStatus", action: "Execute", actionItem: class_action}),
                                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                                            success: function(output) {
                                                if(output){
                                                    console.log(output); 


                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    console.log("Nothing returned");

                                                }
                                            },
                                                error: function() {
                                                    console.log("error in the execute call");

                                                }
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                        </script>
                        <?
                    }                        
                }
```

With a controller that looks like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
$action = $_GET["action"];
switch($action){
    case "GetStatus":       
    _setContent();
    break;
    case "Execute": 
    if(isset($_POST['data'])){
        $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
        echo $data;
    }
    break;
```

Ideas? Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `$_GET['action']` when you're posting it? In fact why are you trying to both post it and append it to the URL? Also have you looked at the browser debug tools? What is in the form data made in the request? Is it as you expect, passing through the correct information?

Comment: Great questions! @Styphon I am using the $_GET['action'] to fire the correct case which it is correctly doing as it is looking at the URL parameter action. From there I need to look at the $_POST['data']  to send that information onward. When looking at the debug tools I can't seem to find where the data is being posted though. It appears that only the URL parameters are being posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have `$(document).ready` inside the loop?

Instead, you can use this below code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".actionButtons").click(function() {
    var class_action = $(this).attr('id')
    $.ajax({
      url: url + '?action=GetStatus&action=Execute',
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        action: "GetStatus",
        action: "Execute",
        actionItem: class_action
      }),
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(output) {
        if (output) {
          console.log(output);
        } else {
          console.log("Nothing returned");

        }
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("error in the execute call");

      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
  $currentDir = getcwd();
  $files = scandir($currentDir);
  $count = 0;
  foreach ($files as $name) {
    if(preg_match("/^sma\w*/", $name)){
        $workingFiles = substr($name, strpos($name, "_") + 1);
        $availableActions = explode(".", $workingFiles);
        $class_action = $availableActions[0];
        $buttonName = $class_action;
        $count ++;
        echo "<button id="$class_action" class='actionButtons'>" . $buttonName. "</button>";
    }                        
  }
?>
```

Comment: That's the reason why it wasn't populating the data. I removed the $(document).ready inside the loop and now the data is making it through. Now I need to figure out why it is returning actionItem:
 {jQuery18397275251907154883: 6} but that is a different topic all together that I will look into. THANK YOU GUYS! What a life saver!

Comment: Cool. The reason for the crazy number was due to the var not being set by php in quotes. I had var class_action = <?php echo $class_action;?> instead of var class_action = "<?php echo $class_action;?>". Cool. All fixed. You guys rock!